# How to solve max tokens error in SqlDatabaseChain?

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, openai-api, langchain

Currently, I am using gpt-3.5-turbo model.

Scenario:

I am using PostgreSQL database. In that I have thousands of records. When SqlDatabaseChain Model create SQLQuery. At that time I want to create the query bases on ILIKE operator.also I have change the prompt based on my requirement.

Based on my prompt it generates SQLQuery like this:

```
Select * from table_name
Where column1 ILIKE '% user question %' or column2 ILIKE '% user question %';
```

Problem:

When above query execute I am getting max token error.

```
Error: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 
8450 tokens (8194 in your prompt; 256 for the completion). Please reduce your 
prompt; or completion length.
```

To solve this error I have tried to change prompt. But nothing works.

Comment: So you reduced your total tokens to down to 4097?